# Struts2 ignoring Action class value properties from applicationContext

Tags: java, struts2

I'm not sure why Struts is not setting a simple String property defined in the `applicationContext.xml` for an Action class.  It is setting a reference but not a `String` value property. Is as if Struts ignores these properties because I tried something like this

```xml
<property name="IDontExistInActionClass" value="MyValue" />
```

and Struts does not complain when instantiating the Action class since setter does not exist. But the `userBO` reference is actually getting set in Action class, so its weird.
Maybe I'm doing something dumb, so I appreciate a second pair of eyes.

Just to mention that this is working for Action classes that do not implement the `SessionAware` interface.

**`applicationContext.xml`:**

```xml
<bean id="loginAction" class="LoginAction" scope="prototype">
        <property name="test" value="testing" />
        <property name="userBO" ref="userBO" />
</bean>
```

**`Struts.xml`:**

```xml
 <package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login"
                class="LoginAction">
                <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/loginmain.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

**Action Class:**

```java
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    private Map<String,Object> session;
    private UserBO userBO;
    private String test;


    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        return "success";
    }

    //~Accessors
    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sMap) {
        this.session = sMap;
    }
    public void setUserBO(UserBO userBO) {
        this.userBO = userBO;
    }
    public void setTest(String value) {
        this.test = value;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class attribute you should use a bean id from the `applicationContext.xml`.

```xml
<package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="loginAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/loginmain.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```